# Elsa Angular Workflow Designer

Tags: angular, elsa-workflows

I've followed [Git](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-designer) instructions and [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-elsa-designer-dkb4t?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) as well and now I have a 1for1 copy of codesandbox example as a project, but cannot manage to get Elsa Workflow Designer to work as I think it should.

I get one single workflow about sending an email from workflow.json file and random elements that I can add to the diagram.

I cannot save anything nor can I find anything in guides on your webpage about making it work.

How do I communicate with the backend part that has a database connection and should run these flows?

When I make these flows, how am I running them?
[image: elsaPage]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active development stopped on Elsa 1 and instead moved to Elsa 2. Elsa 2 comes with a fairly complete web component that has saving workflows baked in as well as other functionality such as managing workflow definitions and instances.